# Aliens from Schisms in Star Trek

Tags: star-trek, aliens

Did the aliens from The Next Generation episode [Schisms](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0708770/) ever return? It seemed like they were probing this universe/dimension, and not for friendly purposes. Do they make any other appearances in other episodes?

Comment: Sadly the answer to most "did x ever return" questions is no.

Comment: @BrianOrtiz not where X is a Terminator. He's always Baaaahk!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From [Memory Alpha](http://memory-alpha.org/wiki/Schisms_%28episode%29) (emphasis mine):

> Director Robert Wiemer, Brannon Braga, and Michael Piller were all disappointed at the look of the aliens, **and decided not to bring them back, despite the open ending**. Braga stated, "I felt they looked like monks – fish monks – and monks aren't terrifying." (Star Trek: The Next Generation Companion)

Comment: Still, that was easily the scariest episode, huh?

Comment: @AtlasMickey - I beg to differ; http://www.thingsnerdslike.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/quark-in-drag.jpg

Comment: Oh god, you're right, there were some DS9 episodes I just could not watch. Anyway I meant scariest TNG episode!

Comment: On the contrary, those fish monks were bloody scary!!

Answer (score 5):

While they did not come back on TV or film, they are featured in [Star Trek Online](http://www.arcgames.com/en/games/star-trek-online). They're called the [Solanae](http://sto.gamepedia.com/Solanae), and they're a servitor race of the [Iconians](http://sto.gamepedia.com/Iconian).